# Sort DataGrid by Combobox displayed value

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, combobox

I have two DataGrids with Parent Child relationship, and both are bounded to data collections. Child DataGrid implements DataGridComboBoxColumn for displaying parent's name instead of id.

**Problem**: `How to sort second DataGrid by this column, but by Parent's Name, not by Id?`

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    x:Name="MainWnd"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="650" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5"/>

    <local:BaseGrid Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWnd, Path=AColView.View}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Aname}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </local:BaseGrid>

    <local:BaseGrid Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWnd, Path=BColView.View}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <local:CaptionExtender Caption="Id"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Bname}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <local:CaptionExtender Caption="Name"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="BparentColumn"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ParentId}"
                                    SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Aname">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>
                    <local:CaptionExtender Caption="Parent"/>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </local:BaseGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private ObservableCollection<A> ACol { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<B> BCol { get; set; }

    public CollectionViewSource AColView { get; private set; }
    public CollectionViewSource BColView { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ACol = new ObservableCollection<A>();
        BCol = new ObservableCollection<B>();

        AColView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = ACol };
        BColView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = BCol };

        InitializeComponent();

        BparentColumn.ItemsSource = ACol;

    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // add parents
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
            ACol.Add(new A { Id = i, Aname = "Parent " + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });

        // add children
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i)
            BCol.Add(new B { Id = i, Bname = "Child " + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), ParentId = (i % ACol.Count) + 1 });
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Aname { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Bname { get; set; }
}
```

[Here is the entire solution](http://www.solidfiles.com/d/325d94041f/)

this is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: just add CanUserSortColumns="True"

Comment: does not matter, still sorting by id (selectedvalue), not Name (DisplayValue)

Comment: Not clear "How to sort second DataGrid by this column, but by Parent's Name, not by Id?"

Comment: are you trying to sort the second grid based on the parent grid sorting?

Comment: @makc, no, theirs sortings are independent.
P.S. i've posted image of desired result in second link of question

Comment: the question isnt clear enough try explaining (show printscreens) of what happens when you push the sort button

Comment: printscreens are in second link in question

Comment: First column (id) - is Id of Parent's record

Comment: set DataGrid CanUserSortColums to true and each column DataGridTextColumn  CaUserSort also to true.
if it wont work please post your local:BaseGrid Xaml and its style

Comment: all solution code posted in first link in question description.